# How to use HFS formatted pen drive in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, hfs

I recently used disk utility in my mac book pro to format my 8 GB pen drive to install OS X. After that I formatted my pen drive from disk utility as FAT32 so that I would be able to use it in windows. But in windows the pen drive does not show up. When I right click on my computer and click manage and then disk management, the pen drive is listed there, but it doesn't show up in the explorer and I cant use it. I tried to do many things but I'm still not being able to use it in windows though I can use it in Mac OS X. Could anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, in Disk Management, right-click any of the partitions on the drive and click "Delete Partition". Make sure you do this for any partition on the drive until they all are gone. Then right-click and click "Create Partition". Create a FAT32 partition and make it fill the whole space.

Now your flash drive (thumb drive or whatever you call it) can be used on any computer.

Answer (score 0):

I use [MacDrive](http://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediafour.com%2Fproducts%2Fmacdrive%2F&ei=C666SvuXOdmSjAe8tKT0BQ&usg=AFQjCNHaE-QSuNbIXmuOBymEVCyy_cWKxg) 7. it's not free though. There are a few free ones on the web. Google for "HFS+ Explorer"

Answer (score 0):

Windows is very fussy about partitioning, and what it expects.  I have always found it better on the Mac, to just partition it as a single Fat16 partition.  Fat32 vs Fat16 for a 8 Gb drive is not going to be that much of a significant difference.

Then, if you want to reformat it as a Fat32 partition when it's visible on the Windows side, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning a drive letter in Disk Management?

You can use [this tutorial](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3400.html) to see how to do that. Just click "Add..." in stead of "Change..." in figure 3.

Answer (score 0):

use Disk Management to delete all partitions, then create a new partition and format with FAT32.

Answer (score 0):

Use [HFS Explorer](http://hem.bredband.net/catacombae/hfsx.html) to show your HFS partition in Windows.